# Is this the reason why fread/fwrite has 2 `size_t` arguments?

Tags: memory, c

It just came to me that, the C standard I/O functions `fread` and `fwrite` are having 2 `size_t` arguments because of I guess possibly, that on some systems, there may be more memory of which whose size can be represented in a single `size_t` type.

With 2 `size_t`s, 1 for element size, another for elements count, caller will be able to read/write more data than can be measured with a single `size_t`.

I find it reasonable with some ancient x86 processors with "near" addressing.

Is this thinking right? What's the real history here?

Comment: `calloc` also takes 2 `size_t` parameters.  To me these all feel like a nod to the fixed-sized record orientation of file systems of other operating systems that were in existence when UNIX was created.

Comment: unlikely. Anything you read must go into a buffer. That buffer can either be a static array (whose maximum size is a   size_t ) or be allocated from  malloc (whose maximum size is a size_t again).

Comment: What about just the fixed-size record orientation of many data processing algorithms? I think this is more generic than filesystems.

Comment: @tofro: Some file systems used data represented as a sequence of fixed-sized records, and may not have allowed for updating bytes within a record via any means other than reading the whole record into a buffer, modifying the appropriate parts, and writing it back.

Comment: @tofro: I would not be at all surprised if there were some pre-standard implementations where e.g. specifying a size of 30 and a record count of 10 would cause first thirty bytes of each of ten records to be written with data taken from memory, and the remainder padded with a platform-specific value such as 0 or ~0.

Comment: @supercat I'm afraid my comment (or the original question) hasn't been understood: The OP seems to assume that by using more than one `size_t`-sized argument, the API allows to theoretically transfer SIZE_T_MAX * SIZE_T_MAX bytes. Because you can't define a buffer of that size, that assumption is wrong.

Comment: @tofro: The Standard does not require that implementations provide any means of creating objects larger than `size_t`, but also does not forbid implementations from providing such mean.  The Standard has no jurisdiction over the behavior of any objects created by means beyond those given in the Standard, regardless of size, and thus implementations which allow objects larger than `size_t` to be created would be allowed, but not required, to implement fread/fwrite in a way that supports them.

Comment: @tofro: Note also that if `calloc(5000,1000000);` returns non-null, the resulting allocation will be large enough to hold an object object of any type whose size doesn't exceed 5,000,000,000 bytes, but the allocation itself isn't object of any such type (or any type whatsoever, for that matter).  If the largest type that would be supported by some implementation would be 4294967295 bytes, then no type would exceed 5,000,000,000 bytes and thus the allocation would be large enough to hold an object of any type, period.

Comment: @supercat I dare to challenge that (explicitly, it doesn't, implicitly it does): `size_t` is the return type of `sizeof`. If allocation of objects larger than SIZE_T_MAX (which is typically MAXULONG) would be allowed, how could a standard-conformant `sizeof` be implemented?

Comment: @tofro: The `sizeof` function requires as an argument a type, an lvalue, or a value.  An allocation received from `calloc` is none of those things.  A bigger issue would arise with `ptrdiff_t`, but if an implementation wouldn't allow the declaration of any type, lvalue, or value larger than 2147483647 bytes, and one assumes `char*p1,*p2;` and `p2` is set to `p1+ofs` for ofs >0, there would be no possible array object that would contain both `p1` and `p2+(2147483648-ofs)`.  Thus, adding any value (2147483648-ofs) or larger to `p2` would not yield a pointer to the same array object, and...

Comment: ...the Standard would have no jurisdiction over the effects of such an action.  An implementation could choose to extend the semantics of the language by implementing such addition in a manner consistent with the addressing semantics of the underlying execution environment, but the question of whether to do so would be outside the Standard's jurisdiction.

Comment: @supercat What you're saying is "you can, but doing so will break standard-conformant programs". Which effectively tells me "you can't". With `ptrdiff_t` typically being half the range of `size_t`(because it's signed) you'd run into that problem even earlier (because you cannot sensibly express the difference between two pointers into that calloc-returned object anymore..

Comment: @tofro: Doing so would not break strictly conforming programs, since the Standard only defines the behavior of ptr+int and ptr-int in cases where the result would point at, or just past, the same array object as the original.  It does not define cases where it doesn't point to the same array, even if the resulting address would fall within the same allocation as the original object resides.   As for programs that are conforming but not strictly conforming, the Standard generally allows implementations to process such programs in meaningful or meaningless fashion at their leisure.

Comment: @supercat I'll stop here. This discussion might be of academical, but in no way of practical value.

Comment: Compare https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/616107/5132 .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AT&T's documentation for `fread` and `fwrite` that pre-dates `size_t` is quoted below.  But first, to answer the title question:

1. Both functions are designed for objects, not characters.  This is evidenced by the return value being a count of the *objects* read or written, not the number of *characters*.
2. Each function may read/write fewer objects than requested.  Well-written code will make another attempt to read/write the remaining objects.  (This is also true of the character I/O.)  The code to re-attempt reading/writing is a lot simpler if you need to only keep track of the number of objects, instead of the number of characters (which then requires dealing with alignment issues).
3. The original implementation used the `int` type for both the number of objects and the size of the objects.  When `size_t` and other `_t` types were introduced, those two arguments needed to retain the same type, to avoid breaking existing source code and compiled libraries.

It has very little to do with the size of memory.

---

The use of `size_t` and other `_t` data types did not appear until K&Rv2.  Before then, the arguments to standard library functions were of `int` and `long` types.  For example, *The C Programmer's Handbook*, AT&T Bell Laboratories, February 1984, p. 50 states (C++ style comments are my addition):

> BLOCK I/O
>
> *Manual Page* -- The functions in this section are on the *fread(3S)* manual page.
>
> *fread* -- Read specified number of bytes (characters) from stream.
>
> - Synopsis:
>
> ```
>     int fread (ptr, size, nitems, stream)
>     char *ptr;
>     int size, nitems;    // <--- THEY WERE BOTH INT
>     FILE *stream;
> ```
>
> *fwrite* -- Write specified number of bytes to stream.
>
> - Synopsis:
>
> ```
>     int fwrite (ptr, size, nitems, stream)
>     char *ptr;
>     int size, nitems;    // <--- THEY WERE BOTH INT
>     FILE *stream;
> ```

[image: C Handbook page 50]

`size_t` was established by the time the second edition of *The C Programming Language*, Kernighan and Ritchie, 1988 was written.  The functions in question are described on p. 247:

> B1.5  Direct Input and Output Functions
>
> `size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nobj, FILE *stream)`
>
> `fread` reads from `stream` into the array `ptr` at most `nobj` objects of size `size`.  `fread` returns the **number of objects read**; this may be less than the number requested.  `feof` and `ferror` must be used to determine status.
>
> `size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nobj, FILE *stream)`
>
> `fwrite` writes, from the array `ptr`, `nobj` objects of size `size` on `stream`.  It returns the **number of objects written**, which is less than `nobj` on error.

Comment: The C Standard specifies that the stride of an array is always equal to the size of the constituent elements.  An implementation could make `sizeof (struct foo)` be three, but only if neither the structure nor any element within it had any alignment requirement.  The size of `char blob[100][3];` would be specified as precisely 300, and `fwrite(blob, 3, 100, someFile)` would need to write 300 consecutive bytes.  I can think of no way that `fwrite` could meaningfully allow for padding of objects in memory as you suggest.

Comment: @supercat: Irrelevant.  There was no C standard *yet* when `fread` and `fwrite` were created.

Comment: Could you please provide a proof of your bolded conjecture by pointing to a versions of the source code of `fwrite` ?

Comment: @DrSheldon: I don't think the fact that an array's stride is equal to the size of the constituent elements has changed since any documented pre-standard version of the language.  See page 7 of https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/cman.pdf for information about the pointer + operator which forms the basis of array subscripting.

Comment: I'm not convince by your alignment argument. In particular, let's consider your hypothetical compiler where `sizeof(struct foo)` is 3, but an array of 100 `struct foo`s takes 400 bytes. Now, what is that compiler going to do with `struct bar { char a; char b; char c; }`? Is an array of 100 `struct bar`s also going to be padded to 400 bytes? That seems pretty crazy, since each struct is just three chars. But if not, how will `fread` know which kind of array it's reading data into?

Comment: Supercat is right. I used to work at Bell Labs, had the original pre-standard compiler documentation in the department library, and even filed a bug report against the compiler. The C standard documented existing behavior of the K&R compiler, which is quite fundamental to how C compilers do pointer arithmetic. `&(z[17])` has to be `z+17`, and pointer addition in in increments of `sizeof(struct foo)` bytes.

Comment: Concur. `sizeof z` had better be `sizeof (struct foo) * 100`.  Otherwise `sizeof z[0] != sizeof (struct foo)`, which is crazy talk.

Comment: It may be worth to add at (or after) item 2 that it will only write objects in full or not at all, so if object size times nr of objects does for whatever reason not fir the target storage management size, it will truncate at object borders.

Comment: @Raffzahn: If a stream does not provide any means by which a program can find out with certainty whether a request to read or write 150 bytes could be satisfied in full without first consuming or writing the first 149 bytes, it won't be able to prevent the writing or consumption of partial records.

Comment: @supercat Note that this is about fread/fwrite, not read/write. Both _guarantees_ that objects are always read in full, otherwise an error is reported and needs to be checked for. Partial objects are not reported in the return value. Please compare its documentation.

Comment: @Raffzahn: The function may report an error, but only after having written or consume a partial record.

Comment: @supercat Please read the documentation about doth functions first. They work different than most other.

Comment: @Raffzahn: Already, I just read the documentation for `fread` and `fwrite`.  The N1570 documentation for `fread` states "If a partial element is read, its value is indeterminate",  which seems to acknowledge the possibility of an object being partially read.  Saying that the storage is indeterminate means that it might be overwritten with data that was read, but that the data might be discarded.

Comment: @supercat you might want as well want to read the part about read pointer position after an error. Fread/fwrite are quite different from the rest of the pack. Also it's not important nor relevant if additional data war read or not. Even fread/fwrite aside, it's quite bad practice to assume a buffer retaining (or containing) data beyond what is clearly marked as valid return information. So no need to speculate about non defined behaviour.

Comment: @Raffzahn: I don't care what gets placed at the destination; I just mentioned it because that part of the Standard expressly recognizes the possibility of reading partial records.  N1570 says "The file position indicator for the stream (if defined) is advanced by the number of characters successfully read."  If code asks `fread` to fetch two 1024-byte records, but the underlying OS operation is limited to reads of 256 bytes or fewer, and the sixth read attempt fails without reading any data, how many characters will have been "successfully" read?

Comment: @supercat None as fread does NOT read characters but objects - only objects are successful read and their number as return value. You are arguing about something that neither is defined nor matters in any way. It's as useless as asking how many bits of a ofa faulty character have been received on an assync line. Not relevant.

Comment: @Raffzahn: When processing non-blocking I/O operations with byte-based devices which have no concept of records, the possibility that code might attempt a read while a record is in the process of being received isn't exactly obscure.

Comment: @supercat Sounds to me like using a TTY to display a GUI... fread/fwrite is meant for record operation, not serial devices. And no, it doesn't need to be written in some manual as it's common sense.

Comment: @Raffzahn: Are you suggesting that serial devices should be read exclusively using `fgetc()` and `fputc()`?  The use of a non-zero "size" operand would be intended for use with record-based *data*, but if two systems have serial-port drivers that can process requests to "read/write up to N immediately-available records of S bytes each; leave any partial records pending", being able to write code that uses whole-record I/O would be more convenient than having to keep track of partially-received records at the application level.

Comment: @supercat Last time: READ THE MANUAL (or man pages). F* calls are locking blocked access. There is no immediate premature return. They will not return with less than the requested amount of full records. Unless there's an error. In case of an error (or EOF), position and data after the last full object is none of your business. The behaviour you imply (and seem to expect) is what's provided by read(). A different class of access functions with different handling intended for different use cases. (Also, size=zero is a nop call. It will directly return with a return code of zero)

Comment: @Raffzahn: The `fread`/`fwrite` functions are defined as part of the C Standard Library.  Unix man pages may specify its behavior in more detail than mandated by the Standard, *but only on Unix systems*.  Different systems will behave differently in the scenario where e.g. some programs have a log file open for append-only mode while others have it open in sequential-read-only mode, and where it would be routine for consumers to read all data that's available up to that point but later read more data.  Code which uses fread/fwrite would be portable in usage scenarios where...

Comment: ...everything that will be written by any particular program will be written before any other program reads or writes anything; if an implementation allows files to be opened in modes where fread/fwrite offer stronger guarantees than the C Standard mandates, other usage patterns may be supported without having to change the code that reads and writes log entires.

Comment: @supercat stop wasting time fantasising what functions should do according to you, start reading the manual and accept what is written there. Check [Posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fread.html) which uses exactly the same wording as in ISO/IEC 9899:1999 section 7.19.8.1 "The fread function".

Comment: @Raffzahn: Some file systems allow a file that is open for appending in one process to be read in another which may be oblivious to the fact that the file is open for appending.  If a program attempts to read "up to 4" records of 1024 bytes at a time when the file contains 4000 bytes, blocking until something adds another 96 bytes to the file might sometimes be useful, but it would more often be useful to have such a request merely read the first three records.  Leaving the stream ready to read the next record once another 96 bytes are written would be handy, but not universally supportable.

Answer (score 15):

The point of fread/fwrite is to write *N* elements, each of size *S* bytes.  The API is not a simple 'write this number of bytes' interface.

Thus, for example:

```
struct S { int a, b; float c; };
struct S stuff[92];
fwrite(stuff, sizeof (struct S), 92, stream);
```

(I would not write '92' in real code, but I want the simple formulation in this example)

Thus it has two size values because it needs them to express the intended operation.

(I don't much like the API, but there it is)

It is not that this is arranged just in case one size_t value can't handle the overall size to read/write, because size_t is by definition large enough to hold the size of the largest possible object (it’s defined as “the unsigned integral type of the result of the `sizeof` operator”) — and anything fread/fwrite can handle is a single contiguous object.  To put it another way, given my above code fragement.

```
 size_t sz = sizeof stuff;
```

is guaranteed to be valid.

---

In the *Rationale* for ANSI-X3.159-1989 (the document accompanying the standard that explains why decisions were made). it says

> **size_t**  is the appropriate type both for an object size and for an array bound, so this is the type of **size** and **nelem**.

Now, they were standardizing an existing function, not inventing it, and this just says why the type is now size_t rather than, say, int.  But it's clear they were thinking in terms of reading and writing an array.

Comment: The standard explicitly says that the functions manipulate arrays, so it is indeed clear that the authors were thinking in terms of reading and writing an array ;-).

Comment: That is indeed a strong hint - not sure why I thought to look in the Rationale rather than the standard itself.

Comment: @another-dave: Some people would claim that the Rationale is non-normative, and everything other than the normative parts of the Standard should be ignored, but the distinction between normative and non-normative only matters when evaluating *requirements*.  The actual requirements imposed by the Standard, are too weak to be useful for anything.  If an implementation can process in Standard-defined fashion at least one--possibly contrived and useless--source text which exercises the translation limits given in the Standard, nothing it does with any other could render it non-conforming.

Comment: On reflection, the question was 'why', which I think to be the domain of the Rationale. The Standard is for 'what'.

Comment: "The API is not a simple 'write this number of bytes' interface." 
 — but it is **now** if I'm understanding the *current* POSIX spec for `fwrite` correctly, which specifies the implementation in terms of `fputc` calls — see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/616107/did-fwrite-fread3-offer-different-multiple-items-behavior-on-different-platf for quote in context of a ± duplicate question I coincidently asked on another SE.

Answer (score 4):

For STDIO files with no buffering, referring to "raw" devices, like tapes, it is important how the `write` system calls are issued, because each `write` system call results in a tape block of the specified size (and to read a raw block, a `read` system call of size no less than the block size is required).

The `fwrite`/`fread` API appears to facilitate writing and reading multiple blocks of the specified size, but various [versions of `fwrite`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/third_party/glibc/+/cvs/libc-970720/stdio/fwrite.c#33), including [UNIX V7](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/libc/stdio/rdwr.c) ignore that distinction.

Could be a conceived but never finalized feature.

Comment: The version of `fwrite` you referred to is over twenty years old, [here’s the current version](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/iofwrite.c;h=640b0a7c2be46e05b7c4750ce6f0330ad6e39d3d;hb=HEAD) (which has the same problem).

Comment: Actually, all of them do, even https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/libc/stdio/rdwr.c How inefficient is it to do single byte system calls when there is no buffering?

Comment: @LeoB. If you're referring to the use of `getc` / `putc` in a loop, probably not too inefficient, given [the way they're defined](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/include/stdio.h).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen They are defined in a way to call _flsbuf every time *in the unbuffered mode*. That's not what "unbuffered" means.

Comment: stdio just deals with byte streams, it has no notion of device blocks. I don't think the `fwrite/fread` design is intended to relate to block devices.

Comment: If an application needs to write explicit blocks it has to use the low-level Unix system calls.

Comment: @Barmar That's sadly true because the unbuffered I/O in the STDIO library was not well thought through.

Comment: I think the intent was for it to be a least common denominator, to keep it simple and portable.

Comment: @LeoB. What, in your opinion, was ill-conceived?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I believe that the way the unbuffered mode was implemented in V6 was conceptually incorrect. The proper implementation would have been to perform one write system call per element in fwrite, exactly one write system call in fputs, etc. Instead the behavior in the unbuffered mode is the same as in the buffered mode with a 1-byte buffer (in both cases all write system calls are issued with size 1), and that's silly.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: Some platforms like CP/M don't directly support stream-based I/O with files.  If reads and writes are done in system-block-sized chunks, they can be performed directly.  Doing a partial-block write will require reading a block from disk into a buffer and editing it, and then ensuring that the data gets written back before the buffer gets reused.  On a 32K or 48K system, being able to avoid wasting buffer space can be useful.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: IMHO, the Standard might have been improved if it had specified that if the next I/O operation after `ungetc()` is something other than `getchar()` or `fgetc()`, the `ungetc()` might be ignored, might affect the following operation, or might be left pending until the next `fgetc()`.

Answer (score 1):

The Standard is silent with regard to what happens if the amount of data that is immediately available to be read is smaller than total the request size, but not a multiple of the record size.  The Standard would allow at least three approaches:

1. Block until the enough data is available to fully satisfy the request.
2. Block until at least one full record is available, and then either consume the requested number of bytes (if the request can be fully satisfied) or consume all bytes that are available, and return the number of full records read.
3. Block until at least one full record is available, and then consume as many *full records* of data as are available, *leaving any remaining partial record pending until the next read request*.

Some I/O stream implementations that receive separate "record size" and "record count" values would consume everything that's available from the source, but not report that they read the last partial record, but others may opt instead to read only complete records, and *leave a partial record pending so that it may be read as a part of a complete record once more data is available*.

A program which only needs to accommodate approaches #1 and #3 can be much simpler than one which would also have to accommodate #2 (such a program would need to use a record size of 1 and buffer partial records itself, yielding code that would generally be simultaneously more complicated and less efficient than would otherwise be necessary).

If the Standard didn't separate out the record count and record length fields, it would be impossible for code that will be run on a platform that uses the third approach to benefit from that, except by using platform-specific functions.  By contrast, although code which uses the Standard Library but doesn't support approach #2 would be "non-portable", it would run correctly and interchangeably on *any* implementation that uses the first or third approach.